Definition of "Internal Rate of Return" is not clear/meaningful
There’s a lot of random talk about “internal rate of return”, but it is not clear what it is.
So: What is the precise definition of “Internal Rate of Return” (IRR)?
I thought it was the following:
Let $x=(x_0,x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ (where $n \geq1$) be a stream of cashflows. Then an IRR is a real number r such that
the present value of the cashflows equals 0, i.e.,
$$\sum_{t=0}^{n} \frac{x_n}{(1 + r)^n} = 0.$$
From the get-go, there are issues with this definition. For retaining financial meaningfulness, we must demand $r>-1$. But let’s add this as a condition to the definition. Also, as is well-known there might be “multiple IRRs”. However, let us assume for the moment that we have a condition which guarantees uniqueness of the IRR; for example we might have only one switch of signs in the stream of cashflows (which by Descartes’ rule of signs entails a unique IRR. Note that it will also be strictly greater than -1.)
Yet, even if we assume all these things (which are often not even mentioned), it is still not clear how meaningful all of this is. I’ll give two examples:
(1) Consider the very simple stream of cashflows (+1000, +1000, -10000).  ﻿
It has a root around 1.70156 (which would be considered the IRR), and is monotonically increasing for r nonnegative. Now, I understand that an “IRR” of 1.70156 seems financially quite unnatural, as it corresponds to an interest rate of about +170%, but still mathematically (and according to the definitions so far) it makes perfect sense. However, in this case the “decision rule” which is often mentioned for IRR (namely: “Accept when IRR > COC and reject when IRR < COC”, where COC is the Cost of Capital, i.e., “required rate”) does not work at all. In fact, if we assume that COC=0.01% here, the NPV is -7.81286148417 (so a very bad investment) while the “decision rule” would tell us to accept.
(2) Consider the very simple stream of cashflows (+1000, +100000, -1000).
Note that it is not really a very exotic one, since there’s only one switch of signs: There’s a unique root in the range (-1, + infty).
The unique “IRR” here is just a little bit greater than -1, namely it lies around -0.990001.
It’s not completely clear what is the meaning of this. Of course, in this case for any nonnegative r the NPV is strictly greater than 0, so since the interest rate is normally (?) nonnegative, whatever it is, the NPV seems positive (it is maximal for r=0 actually). So it seems to be a good investment in any case. However, this is an ad hoc reasoning, which also doesn’t follow any formal decision rule.
And many more examples can be constructed…
All in all, I am not convinced of the usefulness of the concept of IRR. Much more problematic, in fact: It isn’t completely clear what is the precise mathematical definition. And even with a precise mathematical definition, the meaningfulness isn’t clear.
Questions:
(1) What is the precise (i.e., mathematically fully rigorous) definition of "IRR"?
(2) What is the precise decision rule associated with it?

It doesn't address any of my questions. Please, next time try reading the post before answering; and do not give meaningless, nonsense replies like this. Much appreciated! Besides, your question, "Did you try websearching?", is almost laughable.

I literally wrote the "decision rule" in my post (which, again, you clearly didn't read): "Accept when IRR > COC and reject when IRR < COC”, where COC is the Cost of Capital, i.e., “required rate”. I have a PhD in math, and I do not make it a habit of not thinking about my questions/doing research before asking. That you personally do not do effort of doing research before asking a question, doesn't surprise me: Your posts so far testify as such. Again, if you do not wish to do any efforts to read, or will not or cannot appreciate the subtleties raised here, then stay out of answering. Thanks.

Apologies; I admit I fired from the waist when I saw you asking for a formal definition that can be looked up

However, I do believe that the Wikipedia article actually addresses some of your questions, pointing out that IRR is indeed a flawed metric.

IRR is really only effective for conventional cashflows, and even then it is limited in usefulness because it assumes that interim cashflows are reinvested at the same rate. Despite only having one sign change, your examples are not conventional cashflows because they begin with multiple inflows.
MIRR will yield more useful results for non-conventional cashflow examples.
For your (+1000,+1000,−10000) example, using a 10% reinvestment rate and financing rate, MIRR is -47.13%, and you'd reject based on decision rule.

Excel has MIRR() function, Google sheets seems to as well.
Plenty of resources for how to calculate MIRR, but here's one that seems fine:  https://corporatefinanceinstitute.com/resources/valuation/modified-internal-rate-of-return-mirr/

You have already identified the precise mathematical definition of IRR - an (not "the", because there can be more than one) interest rate at which you can discount all cashflows to end up with a zero NPV. You have also discovered some of the drawbacks of IRR in certain circumstances. There can be ore than one, or even none.
Those drawbacks do not make it useless in practice, tough. There are many cases where even multiple IRRs can be useful if one of them does not make practical sense.
The practical meaning is this: At what constant interest rate(s) could I borrow or invest the cash flows and end up with the same total cash flow at the end of the project? That definition lets you narrow the mathematical results to ones that make practical sense.
Suppose that you have a project where the calculated IRRs are +10% and -15%. Obviously you can't borrow (and wouldn't invest) money at -15%, so the 10% return is the more practical result. In this case, you would be indifferent between making this investment and borrowing/investing the cashflows at a 10% interest rate. You could certainly use that to compare the project to other projects of similar risk, or to your cost of capital to see if the project is feasible. If a project has an IRR of 5% but your cost of capital is 7%, you wouldn't do it because it will cost you more in interest to fund the project that the project will earn.
But even then, IRR is not always useful. In those cases, other measures of "return" such as payback period, or modified IRR method like Hart describes can be helpful decision tools.
Applying it to your first "simple" example, you have inflows of 1,000 for two years followed by an outflow of 10,000. Mathematically this only makes sense if you can earn 170% interest on the first two inflows in order to pay off the 10,000 debt. Another interpretation is you're effectively borrowing) the 2k at 170% interest, which is obviously ridiculous.
Your second "very simple" stream of cashflows in completely impractical. You are given 1,000 now, 100,000 in a year, and have to pay 1,000 in two years? What kind of "investment" would have that kind of cashflow? It might help you to see the usefulness if you use more realistic cashflow stream, like a project that costs a lot upfront and earns the cost back over time.

For what it's worth the Wikipedia article on irr points to a paper which calls out no less than 18 flaws in this metric and demonstrates that the author's proposed alternative (AIRR) solves them. If I've got the right URI, that paper is available at http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/0013791X.2012.745916

True, IRR is not practical in all contexts, and cannot be taken in a vacuum. If you blindly choose project based solely on IRR you could make bad decisions if you don't look at it through other metrics as well.
